# ButtonStyle not reducing padding

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to get my TextButtons smaller to make more room on the Row.

```
TextButton( // Reply button
    child: Text('Reply'),
    style: ButtonStyle(
        padding: MaterialStateProperty.all<EdgeInsets>(EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 0)),
        tapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
    )
)
```

Here's what it looks like in the Inspector
[image]

Is there any way to get the buttons and the icon up close and personal with each other and get rid of those yellow lines?  I must be missing something.  Is there a margin property I'm missing?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your text button inside an sized box . It will reduce its size.Give dimensions of sized box according to your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

My buttons looked like this before the style was applied:

[image]

this code was added:

```
style: ButtonStyle(
        padding: MaterialStateProperty.all<EdgeInsets>(EdgeInsets.all(2)),
      )
```

and now they look like this:

[image]

`fromLTRB` constructor also works - I cannot say what the problem is with OP code.